# Getting Command Not Valid Error logging into Exchange Server using POP 3

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, pop3

I have an application that monitors an Exchange Server mailbox for incoming mail. It works on other systems, but for one of our customers we are getting an error: `-ERR Command is not valid in this state.`

I don't think it has anything to do with the code itself because we get the same error message when we try logging in using Telnet. The error comes when the User is passed. Just for reference, I have added my login code below.

```
try
{
    tcpClient = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
}
catch (SocketException e) { ... }
String response = "";

try
{
    streamReader = GetStreamReader(tcpClient);
    response = streamReader.ReadLine();
    if (response.StartsWith("+OK"))
    {
        response = SendReceive("USER ", UserName.Trim() + "@" + Domain.Trim());
        if (response.StartsWith("+OK"))
            response = SendReceive("PASS ", Password);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

And the SendReceive method is below:

```
private String SendReceive(String command, String parameter)
{
    String result = null;
    try
    {
        String myCommand = command.ToUpper().Trim() + " " + parameter.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myCommand.ToCharArray());
        tcpClient.GetStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        result = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }
    catch { }   //  Not logged in...
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some POP3 servers do not allow the `USER` command to be used until/unless the connection is using SSL.

In other words, you may need to use the `STLS` command first (if it is supported), or, failing that, you may be required to use a SASL authentication mechanism.

Check the results of the [`CAPA`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2449.txt) command for more information.

Oh, and shameless plug: use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We have already checked, and they do not have SSL enabled. We are connecting on port 110. It sounds like MailKit would be much easier, but my company prefers to create all of their own code.

Comment: If you want more help, you'll need to at least provide the list of capabilities that the POP3 server supports (i.e. the results of the CAPA command).

Comment: You may also want to actually read the specification for POP3 extensions: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2449.txt

Comment: We have not got it working yet, but think it is a configuration issue on their side. When they try to Telnet in, they are getting the same error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's kind of to be expected since I said that some POP3 servers reject authentication over an unencrypted connection, so they would have to send the STLS command and toggle into an SSL-encrypted channel - but that's not possible to do in any telnet program.

Comment: Ask them to send a `CAPA` command and have them check to see if the `USER` capability is listed. If not, then it is exactly as I have said.